# Review audit system on "first posts" suggests you can "vote to close" answers

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, review-audits

I just started doing some reviews and I think I'm starting to get it and how to vote on things correctly. I had an audit and I was surprised by the result:

> Congratulations!
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. You passed. Downvoting, editing, flagging as "very low quality", or voting to close are all appropriate actions in this case.

This would be normal except that the post I reviewed was an answer so you can't "vote to close" (and I can't even do this because I don't have the reputation anyway).

I would suggest that the text should be different for answers and also it could be useful to only suggest the "vote to close" when you have the appropriate reputation.